# Applying ServiceKnownTypeAttribute to WCF service with Spring

Tags: wcf, spring, serviceknowntype

I am trying to apply the ServiceKnownTypeAttribute to my WCF Service but keep getting the error below my config.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
    <object id="HHGEstimating" type="Spring.ServiceModel.ServiceExporter, Spring.Services">
  <property name="TargetName" value="HHGEstimatingHelper"/>
  <property name="Name"    value="HHGEstimating"/>
  <property name="Namespace"  value="http://www.igcsoftware.com/HHGEstimating"/>
  <property name="TypeAttributes">
   <list>
    <ref local="wcfErrorBehavior"/>
    <ref local="wcfSilverlightFaultBehavior"/>
    <object type="System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute, System.ServiceModel">
     <constructor-arg name="type" value="IGCSoftware.HHG.Business.UserControl.AtlasUser, IGCSoftware.HHG.Business"/>
    </object>
   </list>
  </property>

    Error thrown by a dependency of object 'HHGEstimating' defined in 'assembly [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService.Resources.Spring.objects.xml] line 46' : '1' constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in object 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute#25A5628' (hint: specify argument indexes, names, or types to avoid ambiguities).
while resolving 'TypeAttributes[2]' to 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute#25A5628' defined in 'assembly [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService.Resources.Spring.objects.xml] line 46'

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException: Error thrown by a dependency of object 'HHGEstimating' defined in 'assembly [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService.Resources.Spring.objects.xml] line 46' : '1' constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in object 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute#25A5628' (hint: specify argument indexes, names, or types to avoid ambiguities).
while resolving 'TypeAttributes[2]' to 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute#25A5628' defined in 'assembly [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService.Resources.Spring.objects.xml] line 46'

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ObjectCreationException: Error thrown by a dependency of object 'HHGEstimating' defined in 'assembly [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService.Resources.Spring.objects.xml] line 46' : '1' constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in object 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute#25A5628' (hint: specify argument indexes, names, or types to avoid ambiguities).
 while resolving 'TypeAttributes[2]' to 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute#25A5628' defined in 'assembly [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService.Resources.Spring.objects.xml] line 46']
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.ResolveInnerObjectDefinition(String name, String innerObjectName, String argumentName, IObjectDefinition definition, Boolean singletonOwner) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.cs:300
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.ResolvePropertyValue(String name, IObjectDefinition definition, String argumentName, Object argumentValue) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.cs:150
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.ResolveValueIfNecessary(String name, IObjectDefinition definition, String argumentName, Object argumentValue) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.cs:112
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.ManagedList.Resolve(String objectName, IObjectDefinition definition, String propertyName, ManagedCollectionElementResolver resolver) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Config\ManagedList.cs:126
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.ResolvePropertyValue(String name, IObjectDefinition definition, String argumentName, Object argumentValue) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.cs:201
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.ResolveValueIfNecessary(String name, IObjectDefinition definition, String argumentName, Object argumentValue) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.cs:112
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.ApplyPropertyValues(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper, IPropertyValues properties) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.cs:373
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.PopulateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.cs:563
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.ConfigureObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.cs:1844
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.cs:918
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.CreateAndCacheSingletonInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractObjectFactory.cs:2120
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal(String name, Type requiredType, Object[] arguments, Boolean suppressConfigure) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractObjectFactory.cs:2046
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory.PreInstantiateSingletons() in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\DefaultListableObjectFactory.cs:505
   Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.Refresh() in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\AbstractApplicationContext.cs:911
   _dynamic_Spring.Context.Support.XmlApplicationContext..ctor(Object[] ) +197
   Spring.Reflection.Dynamic.SafeConstructor.Invoke(Object[] arguments) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Reflection\Dynamic\DynamicConstructor.cs:116
   Spring.Context.Support.RootContextInstantiator.InvokeContextConstructor(ConstructorInfo ctor) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:550
   Spring.Context.Support.ContextInstantiator.InstantiateContext() in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:494
   Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.InstantiateContext(IApplicationContext parentContext, Object configContext, String contextName, Type contextType, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] resources) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:330
   Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.Create(Object parent, Object configContext, XmlNode section) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:280

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating context 'spring.root': Error thrown by a dependency of object 'HHGEstimating' defined in 'assembly [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService.Resources.Spring.objects.xml] line 46' : '1' constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in object 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute#25A5628' (hint: specify argument indexes, names, or types to avoid ambiguities).
 while resolving 'TypeAttributes[2]' to 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute#25A5628' defined in 'assembly [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService.Resources.Spring.objects.xml] line 46']
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult) +202
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject) +1061
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject) +1431
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission) +56
   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey) +8
   System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetApplicationSection(String sectionName) +45
   System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetSection(String sectionName) +49
   System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String configKey) +6
   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName) +78
   Spring.Util.ConfigurationUtils.GetSection(String sectionName) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Util\ConfigurationUtils.cs:69
   Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.InitializeContextIfNeeded() in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextRegistry.cs:340
   Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.GetContext() in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextRegistry.cs:206
   Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String reference, Uri[] baseAddresses) in l:\projects\spring-net\trunk\src\Spring\Spring.Services\ServiceModel\Activation\ServiceHostFactory.cs:66
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +11687036
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +42
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +479

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/HHGEstimating.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Error creating context 'spring.root': Error thrown by a dependency of object 'HHGEstimating' defined in 'assembly [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService.Resources.Spring.objects.xml] line 46' : '1' constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in object 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute#25A5628' (hint: specify argument indexes, names, or types to avoid ambiguities).
 while resolving 'TypeAttributes[2]' to 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute#25A5628' defined in 'assembly [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [IGCSoftware.HHG.WebService.Resources.Spring.objects.xml] line 46'.]
   System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +11592858
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +194
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext) +176
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +275
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug :
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET-1262

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are applied to classes at compile time and baked into the metadata. You **cannot** apply attributes to classes with Spring.NET at runtime. [Add the known types to the data contract serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731806.aspx) in your web.config:

```
<system.runtime.serialization>
    <dataContractSerializer>
        <declaredTypes>
            <add type="BaseType, SomeAssembly">
                <knownType type="ConcreteType, SomeAssembly" />
            </add>
        </declaredTypes>
    </dataContractSerializer>
</system.runtime.serialization>
```

Comment: This is not correct. I tried your idea, but no go.  The Spring.ServiceModel.ServiceExporter has specific properties (TypeAttributes and MemberAttributes) to apply Attributes to the class and memebers. I think my problem is that Spring is not choosing the correct overloaded contructor for the Attribute.